# Graphics.Drawstring WordWrap is not as expected

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In my billing application, bills are printed using Graphics.DrawString method, etc. When using Graphics.DrawString with word wrap to draw the ItemName it wrap words into many lines. so it is consuming many rows.

I recreated the problem using simple code. With this code I'm expecting output like the following image:
[Expected Output designed using MS Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14CC7.jpg)

This is my sample code.

```
 string FONTNAME = "Tahoma";
 text = "C# is a simple, modern, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language";
 e.Graphics.DrawString(text, new Font(FONTNAME, 12, FontStyle.Bold), drawBrush, new RectangleF(0, 0, 100.0F, 200F), new StringFormat());
 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(drawBrush), 0, 0, 100.0F, 200F);
```

But I'm getting the following output:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOdh.jpg)

Is there any option to break the words instead of word wrap ?

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. WordWrap will not break the words, it will wrap on spaces.

Comment: My question is, is there any option to break the words

Comment: Whatever you want to call that first version, it is most definitely *not* word-wrap.  There seems to very little point in painting anything like that, no user would ever appreciate it.  If you *have* to then it is entirely up to use Graphics.MeasureString() to find out what can fit on each individual line.

Comment: @HansPassant   :Can you please helpme  with a sample code ?

Comment: Related (with code that works) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337074/system-drawing-drawstring-weird-wrapping-of-long-string?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Graphics.DrawString` does not have any option to break on characters (as opposed to whole words).

To control wrapping, you can pass a `StringFormat` object initialised with a `StringFormatFlags`. The only relevant flag is [`StringFormatFlags.NoWrap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx). The .NET documentation isn't very helpful, but if we look at the [GDI+ documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534181.aspx) (which is the underlying library), we read:

> **StringFormatFlagsNoWrap**
>
> Specifies that the wrapping of text to the next line is disabled. … When drawing text within a rectangle, by default, text is broken at the last word boundary that is inside the rectangle's boundary and wrapped to the next line.

Thus, the only options are wrapping at word boundaries, or performing no wrapping at all.

To get the output you want, you will need to measure character-by-character and draw multiple strings (one for each line).

Comment: Thanks for your response @BradleyGrainger.

Comment: Now I achieved the result by replacing all blank spaces in the string with dots(**.**).