# System.Drawing.DrawString() weird wrapping of long string

Tags: c#, console-application, system.drawing

## Update: I would like to answer my own question with code that helped me solve the issue. It was submitted by Bradley but tweaked to work for me and may help others as well. But I can't answer until it is reopened.  The linked duplicate provides a method, but no code.  A code based answer to this question would be helpful to the community

I'm having some slight issues with the formatting of the text drawn on an image inside of my console application. The text I'm trying to draw is:

> BAS2016=PTR=E30BAS2010=(S20)$W30$PTO2016=N5W20N5(W20N10)(S10W20)S5W5S5E10N10(E15N5)(S5E15)S10E25$W25N10(W15N5)(S5W15)S10W10S15BAS2020=S15PTO2013=S5E20S5(E20S10)(N10E20)N5E5N5W10S10(W15S5)(N5W15)N10W25$E25S10(E15S5)(N5E15)N10E10N15W65$E65N15$.

My method call is:

```
RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, 320);

graphics.DrawString(fullTrav, defaultFont, Brushes.Black, rectF);
```

The output from that is:

[image: get]

This output is only with whatever is the default **StringFormat** for the Rectangle. It wraps fine but it seems to treat characters differently and pushes newlines before the border, depending on what characters are upcoming. I've tried **StringFormatFlag.FitBlackBox** to no avail but haven't gone through each and every flag.

What I want to get is:

[image: want]

This desired output is one that looks more like a square/rectangle and has less word wrap formatting.

#### Is there a way to format the Rectangle so that it will not give characters special treatment and word wrap purely on the concept of when text hits the Rectangle border?

Comment: @BradleyUffner That post is helpful. I searched for hours but never found that one. My string does not have words (or spaces), though, so my problem doesn't involve wrapping at word boundaries. It's wrapping on some special characters but not others. It's almost like it's following a hidden rule that cannot be influenced.

Comment: Nah, the answer won't work here.  I don't think that method is flexible enough to give you what you want (the drawing code not considering closeparens valid places to break lines). Which means you might have to go even deeper https://www.codeproject.com/tips/773878/drawing-text-with-wrapping-and-text-alignment or change the close parens to a different character (square bracket?) and see if the line break logic doesn't crap on that.

Comment: @Will Unfortunately, the code used to create the string is not my own. It's a predetermined code that I'm trying to print :\ It's not the end of the world to print it like this it just looks awful lol

Comment: It's the same issue though.  .NET uses multiple criteria for determining a "word", the most obvious is a space character, but as you are seeing, punctuation and special characters can also count as word boundaries.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Well I guess I'll just delete this if that's the only option: Word wrap or no wrap. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You can still draw the text the way you want, you just have to do a little more work.  As the linked answer says, go character by character, measuring the string so far, until it hits the end of the box, then remove the last character, print your line, and advance to the next line.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I may try that. I marked as duplicate instead of deleting for that reason. Hopefully having another question will help future searchers.

Comment: I was bored, so I made this for you. https://pastebin.com/2ezTbVfz. It was done in LINQPad, so it may look a little odd. It creates this https://imgur.com/a/jy1jg

Comment: Thanks! That will be helpful. I honestly was deciding whether or not it was worth the time to attempt haha.

Comment: It does have a few issues. Sometimes a character goes off the right by a few pixels and gets cropped.  That can be fixed by changing the `while` to something like `while (lineLength < bmp.Width - 5 && currentChar <= str.Length)`.  Use whatever number gives you the right padding for your font size.  I'm not sure why `MeasureString` isn't giving the exact width.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I voted to reopen so I could post the code that worked for me (mainly yours but with small tweaks for allowing for individual character breaking). Any votes to reopen so I can answer and potentially help others are appreciated :)

Comment: @Hank Agreed, the linked duplicate provides an accepted method, but no code to implement it. I hope you don't mind, but I moved your reopen comment to the top of the question, and added more information, so that it is more likely to be seen by reviewers.

Comment: @Will Care to throw a bone? :)

Comment: Ya been boned. @BradleyUffner reopened so you can add your answer.

Comment: @Hank I'm going to post my original code also, just so it doesn't get lost in the comments. If you have code based on it, that fits your goal better, feel free to accept your own answer once the waiting period is up.

Answer (score 2):

This small example (written in LINQPad) demonstrates a way to  wrap text that breaks on any character.  Feel free to customize it, and improve it (it leaks some resources, and may truncate a few pixels from the right side) for your needs.

```
void Main()
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(320, 320, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Gray);

        var str = @"BAS2016=PTR=E30BAS2010=(S20)$W30$PTO2016=N5W20N5(W20N10)(S10W20)S5W5S5E10N10(E15N5)(S5E15)S10E25$W25N10(W15N5)(S5W15)S10W10S15BAS2020=S15PTO2013=S5E20S5(E20S10)(N10E20)N5E5N5W10S10(W15S5)(N5W15)N10W25$E25S10(E15S5)(N5E15)N10E10N15W65$E65N15$.";
        var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);           
        int lineIndex=0;
        double lineHeight = font.Height;

        while (str.Length > 0)
        {
            float lineLength = 0;
            int currentChar = 1;

            while (lineLength < bmp.Width - 5 && currentChar <= str.Length)
            {
                string line= str.Substring(0, currentChar);
                lineLength = g.MeasureString(line, font).Width;
                currentChar++;
            }
            g.DrawString(str.Substring(0,currentChar-1),font,Brushes.Black,0,(float)Math.Ceiling(lineIndex*lineHeight),StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            str = str.Substring(currentChar-1);
            lineIndex++;
            currentChar=1;               
        }
    }
    bmp.Dump();
}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

## Answer facilitated by @BradleyUffner.

The only solution to this problem was to measure each character of the string, cutting off the line when the line length hit the limit, and then printing each line individually.

The code is as follows:

```
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    PointF ptF = new PointF(last.textPoints.subCode.X, last.textPoints.subCode.Y + 40);

    int lineIndex = 0;
    double lineHeight = defaultFont.Height;

    while (fullTrav.Length > 0)
    {
        float lineLength = 0;
        int currentChar = 1;
        while (lineLength < 320 && currentChar <= fullTrav.Length)
        {
            string line = fullTrav.Substring(0, currentChar);
            lineLength = graphics.MeasureString(line, defaultFont).Width;
            currentChar++;
        }

        //
        // Optional Code Start
        //
        while (fullTrav[currentChar - 2].ToString().IndexOfAny("(NSEW".ToCharArray()) != -1)
        {
            currentChar--;
        }

        if (currentChar - 1 < fullTrav.Length)
        {
            while (fullTrav[currentChar - 1].ToString().IndexOfAny("1234567890".ToCharArray()) != -1)
            {
                currentChar--;
            }
        }
        //
        // Optional Code End
        //

        graphics.DrawString(fullTrav.Substring(0, currentChar - 1), defaultFont, Brushes.Black, ptF.X, ptF.Y + lineIndex * 20, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

        fullTrav = fullTrav.Substring(currentChar - 1);
        lineIndex++;
        currentChar = 1;

    }
}
```

This code includes and optional area that I used to break on specific characters only. To explain a little, it prevents it from splitting up "N4" or "W17" between two different lines and it prevents a beginning parenthesis "(" from being the last character in a line.

The finished product looks something like:

[image: solved]